# How to draw a complex Gantt chart in react?

Tags: reactjs, charts, gantt-chart, react-google-charts, frappe

I am trying to build a gantt chart, wherein a single row can have multiple horizontal boxes. Something as shown in the below image.
[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEDKv.png).

I have explored following react packages, but seems no one is enough to draw multiple horizontal boxes in a single row as shown in the images.

Packages:

1. react-google-charts
2. frappe-gantt-react
3. react-gantt

Please do suggest some solution. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You seem to be asking us to do your work for you. . That's not how SO works.

Comment: Sure @isherwood, will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a superset of Gantt chart, called **[Timeline chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline)**. That would help one to implement above mentioned chart.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create using recharts. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/scatter-chart-with-cells-forked-d3ndsv. Hope this helps.